# How to set/enforce Apache Camel to run/use only TLS 1.3

Tags: java, spring, ssl, apache-camel

I have a test server written in java that supports TLS 1.3 (checked by command:

```html
openssl ciphers -v | grep TLSv1.3
```

result: New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)

But the client - Apache Camel when trying to send POST to a server, then server response is ERROR. Below is the full response log:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.984 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:304|No available cipher suite for TLS12
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.984 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:304|No available cipher suite for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.985 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:304|No available cipher suite for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.985 CEST|ClientHello.java:678|Consuming ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "DE B4 7F B8 C1 A8 D2 C7 4E 4B 2F 1B E1 EE CC F3 8B E7 1C BC 39 DC 96 4F 22 9B E6 B4 F7 95 34 67",
  "session id"          : "D2 7F 38 74 C4 C1 CD AF FB 04 EB DC FA 33 66 C2 4D 16 7C 2C 7C 13 6A 99 B0 99 26 1B 31 26 74 10",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=myHostname
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [
        {
          "named group": secp256r1
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 04 55 5F F8 49 33 A5 E6   1C 98 99 D2 0C A2 70 B7  .U_.I3........p.
            0010: B7 F2 D9 1D A4 4C D8 44   61 F6 98 77 FB 38 A4 E9  .....L.Da..w.8..
            0020: CC 3D 58 1C AF 99 CA 70   3B 2A E1 95 BC CB 89 27  .=X....p;*.....'
            0030: 72 4E DE 2F A3 7B C6 62   49 7B 1C B3 23 E5 D6 F7  rN./...bI...#...
            0040: 71
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|ClientHello.java:708|Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.3
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: psk_key_exchange_modes
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|PreSharedKeyExtension.java:804|Handling pre_shared_key absence.
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|ServerNameExtension.java:327|no server name matchers, ignore server name indication
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: supported_groups
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: signature_algorithms
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: signature_algorithms_cert
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: extended_master_secret
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: cookie
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: certificate_authorities
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.986 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.987 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.987 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.987 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.987 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.987 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: supported_groups
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.987 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:428|Unsupported signature scheme: dsa_sha256
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.987 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:428|Unsupported signature scheme: ecdsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.987 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:428|Unsupported signature scheme: rsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.987 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:428|Unsupported signature scheme: dsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.987 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:428|Unsupported signature scheme: dsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.987 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:224|Populated with extension: signature_algorithms
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.988 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:428|Unsupported signature scheme: dsa_sha256
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.988 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:428|Unsupported signature scheme: ecdsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.988 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:428|Unsupported signature scheme: rsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.988 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:428|Unsupported signature scheme: dsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.988 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:428|Unsupported signature scheme: dsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.988 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:224|Populated with extension: signature_algorithms_cert
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.988 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.988 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.988 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: cookie
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.988 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: psk_key_exchange_modes
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.988 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: certificate_authorities
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.989 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.989 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.989 CEST|ServerHello.java:714|use cipher suite TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.990 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.990 CEST|ServerHello.java:573|Produced ServerHello handshake message (
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "48 8F 4B 44 8B 85 28 1B 47 D1 7F 97 71 69 A9 F3 41 C5 C5 D6 4A 68 3F 95 BE 87 46 E5 9B 7A D1 10",
  "session id"          : "D2 7F 38 74 C4 C1 CD AF FB 04 EB DC FA 33 66 C2 4D 16 7C 2C 7C 13 6A 99 B0 99 26 1B 31 26 74 10",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "selected version": [TLSv1.3]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "server_share": {
        "named group": secp256r1
        "key_exchange": {
          0000: 04 06 7F 37 27 51 3F BE   D3 FF 4D B0 D3 36 9D 22  ...7'Q?...M..6."
          0010: 4D 56 DC 03 4D 2B C2 D7   35 4C 96 31 D9 F2 3A 70  MV..M+..5L.1..:p
          0020: 37 DE 91 17 7B C4 3B 24   DC 07 BD 99 23 B9 B7 18  7.....;$....#...
          0030: FC 01 06 F6 98 76 8D 34   A2 55 3C 95 DC 93 D5 C8  .....v.4.U<.....
          0040: 59
        }
      },
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.992 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1817|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.992 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1971|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.992 CEST|ServerNameExtension.java:537|No expected server name indication response
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.992 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.992 CEST|MaxFragExtension.java:463|Ignore unavailable max_fragment_length extension
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.992 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|AlpnExtension.java:384|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|EncryptedExtensions.java:137|Produced EncryptedExtensions message (
"EncryptedExtensions": [
  "supported_groups (10)": {
    "versions": [secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
  }
]
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.993 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|X509Authentication.java:270|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha1
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.995 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1093|No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|SEVERE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.996 CEST|TransportContext.java:323|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): No available authentication scheme (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:318)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:274)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:265)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:972)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:961)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:421)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1141)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1077)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:714)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:682)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1401)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1309)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:822)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$200(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:913)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
        at HttpsServerExample2.main(HttpsServerExample2.java:39)}

)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.996 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1619|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 13:58:40.996 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1638|close the SSL connection (initiative)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 14:03:12.919 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:304|No available cipher suite for TLS12
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 14:03:12.919 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:304|No available cipher suite for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 14:03:12.920 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:304|No available cipher suite for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-08-11 14:03:12.924 CEST|ClientHello.java:678|Consuming ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "D9 5E 2E A6 63 EE 12 27 49 40 05 21 F0 6B CD 0A 7F 0E F4 A6 71 6D A6 D4 96 4A FD F6 A5 07 5E 85",
  "session id"          : "0F 75 30 B1 4A 7B 71 A0
```

It looks like Apache-Camel still uses TLSv1.2. How to upgrade to 1.3 ?
Do I need upgrade java ? My java & openssl version is:

> java -version
> openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.382.05.1 (build 1.8.0_382-b05)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.382.05.1 (build 25.382-b05, mixed mode)

[root@myHostname tls1.3_python_java]# openssl version

OpenSSL 1.1.1v  1 Aug 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022)

I want TLS 1.3 communication cipher protocol not TLS 1.2.

**Edit**:
I added TLS1.2 into java.security file to disabled it and restarted Camel:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
    EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

Effect: the same error. Should I restart Java somehow after editing java.security file ?

Comment: **IT IS NOT using TLSv1.2.** The fixed version fields in ClientHello and ServerHello for TLSv1.3 continue to use the value (0x0303) for v1.2, only the contents of the supported_versions _extension_ specify 1.3, and the ones in your trace do. The EncryptedExtensions message also confirms this; it only exists in 1.3 not 1.2. Your error is probably that the server doesn't have a valid cert-and-key. Also neither your server (clearly Java/JSSE) nor a Camel client uses OpenSSL, so OpenSSL version is irrelevant, although having a mismatch between commandline and library is dubious.

Comment: Yes! Maybe, I downloaded cert directly by command : `openssl s_client -servername myHostName -connect api3.getresponse360.pl:443 -showcerts > getResponse360.pem` . But now I get HTTPS code error: 400. In cURL I pass --cacert <path_to_the_same_cert_pem_file> as in Camel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm confused.  You are asking for TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, which is TLS V1.3, but you are setting your TLS version to 1.2.  Your server seems to have TLS V1.3.

In any event, my preferred method for limiting TLS versions is to edit the java java.security file and disable them:

`jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves`

Add TLSV1.2 (if not there already) to the list and see what happens.

Comment: I want to extend apache-camel to allow it to use tls 1.3 to communicate with the server. Now I have errors, because Camel cant hande TLS 1.3. How to upgrade Camel/Java from TLS 1.2 —-> 1.3 ?

Comment: It is not a question of whether or not Camel can handle TLSV1.3.  This is solely a function of the java runtime environment.  Later releases of Java 8 contain TLSV1.3.  TLSV1.3 was not in the initial release of Java 8.  If you have a release of Java 8 that contains TLSV1.3, then please try disabling TLSV1.2 in your Java runtimes java.security file as above.  This will leave only TLSV1.3 available to Java programs.  You don't need to do anything in Camel.

Comment: Yes, option dk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1.2 etc. works correctly! I checked it. But it was a problem with certificate. I downloaded cert by browser and domain didn't match on different host. You need to download cert through linux from specific host where your connections will be made. After I downloaded cert from direct host no longer error /Unable to find valid certification path. Another story that still I have failure: HTTP Code: 400. cURL with same Request Body and Headers works with external API. But THE SAME request parameters don't work from Apache-Camel! I am looking solution